# How to transfer git repo to a different account while keeping commits history but changing the private information?

Tags: git, github

I have multiple GitHub accounts including one that is tied to my real name. I'd like to consolidate them into a single github account and transfer all my repos to this new account while keeping their histories intact, except replacing the commit author (and all info tied to my old account) with the new account's information.

I have tried using github's repo ownership transfer, but that keeps the commit info linking to my old account which is an issue.

How would you go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to keep the commits as-is, but register all your used email addresses to your new account (https://github.com/settings/emails)

This way, all your old commits will be linked to your new account.

Actually changing the old commits is not so easy. You would need to rewrite the complete history, which would change all the SHA hashes.